# Project running slow

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an application interested in guitar chords in android studio. There are 2 spinners to choose chord and there is an imageview to show the chord diagram on the screen. When user select the chord its diagram appears on screen and plays. Unfortunately it really works slow. How can i make it faster?
Here's Java Class

```
public class Chords extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] notes = {"A", "B", "C","C#","D", "E", "F","F#", "G"};
    String[] mode = {"m", "m7", "5", " ", "7M", "dim", "aug", "sus2"};
    Spinner sp;
    Spinner spinner2;
    TextView textView;
    TextView t;
    TextView t2;
    MediaPlayer mySound,mySound2,mySound3,mySound4,mySound5,mySound6,mySound7;
    private static ImageView imgView;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.aminor,R.drawable.eminor,R.drawable.a_major,R.drawable.cmajor,R.drawable.gmajor,R.drawable.dminor,R.drawable.bminor};
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.chords_screen);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        t2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //creating adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, notes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mode);

        //setting drop down list type
        adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter_state2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //setting adapter to spinner
        sp.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter_state2);

        //setting listener to spinner
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.am);
        mySound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.em);
        mySound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.amajor);
        mySound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cmajor);
        mySound5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gmajor);
        mySound6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dminor);
        mySound7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bm);

        if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            mySound.start();
            imgView.setImageResource(images[0]);
        }
        if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
            mySound3.start();
            imgView.setImageResource(images[2]);
        }
        if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            mySound7.start();
            imgView.setImageResource(images[6]);
        }
        if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
            mySound4.start();
            imgView.setImageResource(images[3]);
        }
        if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            mySound6.start();
            imgView.setImageResource(images[5]);
        }
        if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 5 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
            mySound2.start();
            imgView.setImageResource(images[1]);
        }
        if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 8 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
            mySound5.start();
            imgView.setImageResource(images[4]);
        }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: replace if's statements with else if

Comment: Store return values from a function call into a variable so that you don't have to repeat the function call several times.

Comment: Also, you should try to determine which part of the code is actually causing the app to run slowly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice every if statement has sound and image.How can i store them as a return value.

Comment: All of these are good advice, but they're micro-optimizations at best.  They'll save nanoseconds.

Comment: setImageResource is problem, how big are images?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan so what should i do?It really runs slow when select a chord.Im waiting 15 sec.

Comment: See my answer.  Their suggestions are all good from a style/maintainability perspective, but the real problem is your media player usage.

Comment: @MaciejSikora averagely 35-40 Kb.They're small

Comment: @GabeSechan how can i determine  which part of the code runs slowly.Im new on android studio.

Comment: You can always time it-  get the time before you run the code, get the time after, and subtract.  Technically you should do that a bunch of times and average, but doing it once will give you a good rule of thumb.  The rest is a lot of common sense programming-  think about how what you're calling is likely to be implemented and what it will be doing.  The more complex it is, the more likely that's your problem.

Comment: For example, every if statement has `sp.getSelectedItemPosition()`. There is no need to repeat this so many times.

Answer (score 3):

```
mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.am);
mySound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.em);
mySound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.amajor);
mySound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cmajor);
mySound5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gmajor);
mySound6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dminor);
mySound7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bm);
```

Don't do this.  Create 1 MediaPlayer.  MediaPlayer is a big bulky object, creating 7 of them is extremely painful and slow.  You probably shouldn't even be creating a new one on every click, it should be created in your oncreate and a new data source set instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.But how can i play 7 items using one mediaplayer object?Can you code it please?I'd be grateful

Comment: Look at setDataSource.  It tells the media player what file, uri, etc to play.

Comment: I researched but couldnt find for multiple mp3 tracks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it runs faster but when click a spinner or button it opens slow.

```
    if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.am);
        mySound.start();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[0]);

    }
    else if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
        mySound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.amajor);
        mySound3.start();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[2]);
    }
    else if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
        mySound7 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bm);
        mySound7.start();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[6]);
    }
    else if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
        mySound4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cmajor);
        mySound4.start();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[3]);
    }
    else if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
        mySound6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dminor);
        mySound6.start();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[5]);
    }
    else if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 5 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
        mySound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.em);
        mySound2.start();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[1]);
    }
    else if (sp.getSelectedItemPosition() == 8 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
        mySound5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gmajor);
        mySound5.start();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[4]);
    }
```